# Is declaring a field volatile enough in case of a single writing thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

Consider the following code:

```
public class MyAtomicInteger {
    private volatile int value;

    public int get() {
        return value;
    }

    public void increment() {
        value++;
    }

}
```

I was asked the following question during an interview: is this code thread-safe if only one thread calls `increment()` and multiple threads can call `get()`?

I understand that if we have multiple writing threads, race conditions can occur. However, when there is a single writing thread in each reading thread we will get the values in order, i.e. we won't read `0` after `1` because write of `1` happens before the first read of `1` and, consequently, all subsequent reads in the same thread. Is this reasoning correct, or I am missing something?

Comment: Re, "Thread safe if only one thread..." That means the same as "_NOT_ thread safe." We call a class/module/procedure/etc. "thread safe" if it behaves in a reasonable and well-documented way when _multiple_ threads are allowed to use it at the same time. Your `get()` operation is "thread safe" because if threads call it while one other thread calls `increment()` one time, then all of the `get()` callers are guaranteed either to get the value before or the value after. Your `increment()` method is not thread safe because you can't predict what will happen if more than one thread calls it.

Answer (score 2):

It is sufficient to have only volatile.

What is required is that a happens-before edge needs to exist between the read and the write. Otherwise, there is a data race. And a volatile generates such happens before edges.

These happens-before edges prevent reading an older value after you read a newer value. A correctly synchronized program in Java is only allowed to have sequential consistent executions. Every sequential consistent execution is automatically coherent because coherence is a relaxation of sequential consistency. And coherence prevents reading an older value after a newer value is read.

[note]
If you would have concurrent increments, with a volatile variable you will not have a data race, but you will have a race condition.

Comment: "The term race condition is often confused with the related term data race, which arises when synchronization is not used to coordinate all access to a shared nonfinal field." (from Java Concurrency in Practice). In case of concurrent increments we have access without synchronization to a nonfinal fied. So why this is not a data race?

Comment: In simple terms: the volatile read/write are synchronization operations and all synchronization operations are excluded from data-races.

Answer (score 1):

Normally problems come from needing atomicity for the read-modify-write that is `value++;`. Since a single thread is doing it, it's just one thread writing value, other threads reading value.

That's what `volatile` provides (visibility from changes done by threads) and that's all what is required.

Of course everyone knows that it's still not safe to design code like that. Someone adds another thread and *bam* your code is broken without you noticing anything.